# Spring data , mongodb - pessemistic locking?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, locking, spring-data

We are using spring data repositories in our project.
On our mysql DB its very easy to pessimistic lock a query (simple annotation).

Is it possible to achieve a pessimistic lock on the mongo repositories as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JPA as well, if so it has support for Pessimistic & Optimistic locking strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is not meant for usecase which involves transactions. Check if it possible to de-normalize you data model in Mongo. Having said that I have had to do transactions in one of my projects. We wrote custom code to handle this using AOP